# How do I register and use a MediatR pipeline handler, for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I'm using ASP.NET Core, the latest MediatR, and MediatR [extension for Core's DI](http://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).

I'm trying to set up a pipeline with validation, [using the official blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/10/13/mediatr-pipeline-examples/). The example [is here](http://gist.github.com/jbogard/473abe269278a3f8d9b55b8913f39d3e#file-validatorpipeline-cs).

I don't understand how to register/use that pipeline class. Another [blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/09/09/tackling-cross-cutting-concerns-with-a-mediator-pipeline/) shows how to do this, but I think it's for AutoFac.

How do I do this for the built-in container?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The posts you mention use MediatR 2.x.
MediatR 3.0 has been released not long ago, and has built-in support for pipelines. I would suggest you read the [associated documentation](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors).

In short, MediatR now exposes a `IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>`, and the instances you register in your container will be discovered automatically by MediatR when constructing the handler.

Here's what it could look like in ASP.NET Core:

```cs
public class MyRequest : IRequest<string>
{
}

public class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<MyRequest, string>
{
    public string Handle(MyRequest message)
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}

public class TracingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Before");
        var response = await next();
        Trace.WriteLine("After");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Very simple, a request, a handler and a behavior that does some "logging".

Registration is very easy, too:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(TracingBehaviour<,>));
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var mediator = provider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

var response = await mediator.Send(new MyRequest());
```

It's just a matter of registering the open-generic `TracingBehavior` as a generic implementation of `IPipelineBehavior`.

Comment: I'm curious how the handler gets associated with the pipeline, because I just tried it and it works auto-magically!

Comment: MediatR does it internally. It resolves the request handler through your container, then resolves all the instances of `IPipelineBehavior` and creates a pipeline where all the behaviors are chained and the last element in the chain is the actual handler. It's all happening in the [`RequestHandlerImpl<TRequest, TResponse>`](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/bead0c683b8a001e2f796a623e04b1b333ca702c/src/MediatR/Internal/RequestHandler.cs#L64) class if you're interested in reading the code.

Comment: I just realised the pipeline above would be invoked for ALL requests. Is it supposed to be that way? Can't I have multiple pipelines, and for example, have one for validation where it only processed certain requests, rather than all requests?

Comment: Ok I figured it out: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<MyRequest,string>), typeof(TracingBehaviour<MyRequest,string>));`